# Vectorization of function contains the numerical computation of definite integral in octave

Tags: octave, data-fitting, numerical-integration

I'm trying to fit my data using a formula containing a numerical calculation of definite integrals with infinite limits of integration. For fitting I use octave function `leasqr` that requires vectorization model function. The following code generates error, that occurs when calling a numerical integration.

*nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x387, op2 is 10x2)*

```
function  [fGsAb] = GsAbs (x, p) 
Hw = 3108.0 ;  
fGsAb = Hw ./ (2.4 .* p(1) .*p(2)) .^2 .* (exp ( - (Hw - p(1) .* x) .^2 ... 
./ (2.4 .* p(1) .*p(2)) .^2 )  - exp ( - (Hw + p(1) .* x) .^2  ...
./ (2.4 .* p(1) .*p(2)) .^2 )) ;
endfunction 
function [GsDisp] = gauss_disp(x,  p) 
[GsDisp1, err] = quadgk ( @(z)  GsAbs(z, p) ./(z-x), - inf, x - 0.000001 );
[GsDisp2, err] = quadgk ( @(z)  GsAbs(z, p) ./(z-x), x + 0.000001 , inf  );
GsDisp = GsDisp1 +GsDisp2;
endfunction     
h = [200:15:6000];
pin =[1 250];
dd   =  gauss_disp (h,  pin);
```

If I'm using loop:

```
for i = 1 : length (h)
dd (i) = gauss_disp (h (i),  pin) 
endfor
```

I have no errors, but I cannot use this construction in `leasqr`. How can I get around this restriction?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you defining these functions in a file? Or in the octave terminal directly? And which line is giving you this error?

Comment: I have provided an answer that works around your problem. However, in the future please provide all the relevant information, such as the fact that `leasqr` is a function from the `optim` package, and that this expects a function of a particular form which is why this fails. I had to do a reasonable amount of detective work to guess that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your gauss_disp.m file from this:

```
function [GsDisp] = gauss_disp(x,  p) 
  [GsDisp1, err] = quadgk ( @(z)  GsAbs(z, p) ./(z-x), - inf, x - 0.000001 );
  [GsDisp2, err] = quadgk ( @(z)  GsAbs(z, p) ./(z-x), x + 0.000001 , inf  );
  GsDisp = GsDisp1 +GsDisp2;
endfunction
```

to this:

```
function [GsDisp] = gauss_disp(x,  p)
  GsDisp  = arrayfun(@(z) gauss_disp_elementwise(z, p), x) 
endfunction 

function GsDisp = gauss_disp_elementwise(x, p)
  [GsDisp1, err] = quadgk ( @(z)  GsAbs(z, p) ./(z-x), - inf, x - 0.000001 );
  [GsDisp2, err] = quadgk ( @(z)  GsAbs(z, p) ./(z-x), x + 0.000001 , inf  );
  GsDisp = GsDisp1 +GsDisp2;
endfunction
```

I.e. make your original function into a helper subfunction that only deals with scalar values, and then use that with `arrayfun` to get outputs for the entire range of `x`. This way you can use this in your `leasqr` function, e.g.:

```
y = leasqr(h, dd, pin, @gauss_disp);
```

<sub>PS: the arrayfun syntax is just for convenience. you could have easily used a for loop similar to what you used in your question instead.</sub>

Comment: procrastination at its finest :-) +1

Comment: @Andy I just submitted the Thesis, so I'm allowed, ahahah.

Comment: Thanks, such packaging of fitting function I was looking for.  I think that the 'for' loop is useless for 'leasqr'.

Comment: @Igor what I meant is that the `arrayfun` can be translated to a `for` loop *inside* the `gauss_disp` function. You are right that this needs to be part of the function though, since `leasqr` expects this function to have a particular format.

Comment: @Igor also, if this answer solves your problem, please accept / upvote appropriately :)